# Problem occured in writting CMakeLists about include_directories and add_subdirectory on add_library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to CMake project and
I am trying to write a simple test with libmodbus and paho-mqtt
on VSCode with GCC 8.1.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32.

In my main.cpp both head file can be included normally,

```
#include "modbus.h"
#include "MQTTClient.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(Project_Testbed VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

include_directories(ext/libmodbus)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ext/libmodbus)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC modbus)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/libmodbus/modbus.dll
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)

add_subdirectory(model/model_mqtt)
include_directories(model/model_mqtt)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC model_mqtt)

include_directories(ext/mqtt)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ext/mqtt)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC paho-mqtt3a)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/mqtt/paho-mqtt3a.dll
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

But when I try to do it in subproject(model_mqtt.cpp), like this

```
#include "modbus.h"
#include "MQTTClient.h"


int test(int argc, char *argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt like this

```
project(model_mqtt)

set(mqtt_files
    model_mqtt.cpp
    model_mqtt.h
    )
add_library(model_mqtt ${mqtt_files})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC modbus)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC paho-mqtt3a)
```

It shows: cannot open source file "MQTTClient.h"C/C++(1696)

How could it be? Isn't them the same?

My project structure is like this

```
project
|──ext
|   |──mqtt
|   |    MQTTClient.h
|   |    paho-mqtt3a.lib
|   |    paho-mqtt3a.dll
|   |    etc...
|   |──libmodbus
|   |    modbus.h
|   |    modbus.lib
|   |    modbus.dll
|   |    etc...
|──model
|   |──model_mqtt
|   |    CMakeLists.txt
|   |    model_mqtt.cpp
|   |    model_mqtt.h
|──CMakeLists.txt
|──main.cpp
|──main.h
```

Comment: The call to `include_directories` affects on all executable/libraries created in the same `CMakeLists.txt` and in the descendant `CMakeLists.txt` which are included via `add_subdirectory` **after** that call. So, your call `include_directories(model/model_mqtt)` affects on `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)`, which is called in the same `CMakeLists.txt`, but doesn't affect on `add_library(model_mqtt ${mqtt_files})` called from `model/model_mqtt/CMakeLists.txt`, because call to `add_subdirectory(model/model_mqtt)` is issued **before** `include_directories`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved after I call `add_subdirectory(model/model_mqtt)` after `include_directories`. I should have call all the libraries first.

Comment: The correct solution is to make MQTT and modbus `IMPORTED` libraries, which turns them into actual targets that are visible and usable everywhere in your CMake tree.

Answer (score -1):

You should instead define imported targets as follows. This can either go in the main `CMakeLists.txt` or in `ext/CMakeLists.txt` (in which case strip the `ext` prefix)

```
add_library(Imported::MQTT SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(Imported::MQTT PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/mqtt/paho-mqtt3a.dll
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/mqtt/paho-mqtt3a.lib
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/mqtt
)
```

Now you can simply use `target_link_libraries(TARGET PUBLIC Imported::MQTT)` from anywhere in the project and both the header file and link dependency will be set up for you.